# sudo ant dist failure for Freemind - Cannot run program ".../freemind/check_for_duplicate_resources.sh": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: java, ant, sudo, freemind

I've been trying to install Freemind from source, but I keep facing this error. Any ideas? I am already using sudo, so I don't get the "permission denied" message.

---

```
hache_g@HgFrida:~/Desktop/freemind$ sudo ant dist
Buildfile: /home/hache_g/Desktop/freemind/build.xml
init:
[echo] FreeMind Version = 1.0.1, build 16.
[echo] Checking for duplicate Resource strings

BUILD FAILED
/home/hache_g/Desktop/freemind/build.xml:83: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/hache_g/Desktop/freemind/check_for_duplicate_resources.sh": error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:629)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:670)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:496)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 23 more
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the script?

Comment: You should provide more details about what you did to get the sources and how you installed them.The file is probably simply not not executable. Try to fix that via `chown +x /home/hache_g/Desktop/freemind/check_for_duplicate_resources.sh`. Using sudo for compilation should never be necessary.

Comment: @mttdbrd
 
These are the script's permissions: hache_g@HgFrida:~/Desktop/freemind$ ls -l total 12628 -rw-r--r-- 1 hache_g hache_g 300 abr 12 2014 check_for_duplicate_resources.sh

Comment: @vboerchers I tried to use chown but this showed up:chown: invalid user: ‘+x’I don't know where should I put the new user (I believe that's the problem).

I got the sources from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/freemind/files/ I learned from the readme.txt that I needed to install ant to install the software, and it also said that simply running ant dist would do the job. It didn't.

Comment: I've got it running with chmod =) So, thank you @mttdbrd. 

There's only one additional issue: I can't find freemind in my applications section in Ubuntu. Why would that be? Y can only run it by executing ant run inside freemind's directory through bash.

Comment: @hachege The Ubuntu menu only knows about programs that you tell them about. The Debian/Ubuntu .deb packages take care of it but without a package you have to do it yourself. See e. g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/407708/how-to-create-a-menu-item-for-eclipse-in-ubuntu-13-10 for how to do that